# Threads run correctly in javafx not correctly in java

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

Can somebody explain to me why my aplication runs correctly when I use javafx with a gui (with for example one button) and why it doesn't when running the same method without a gui only in main? 
Here is example:

**JAVAFX**

Simple controller:

```
    public class ParserGuiController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private Button startButton;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        startButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    Parser.parseText();
                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

parseText() method

```
public static void parseText() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= 2 ; i++){
            executorService.execute(new GetLinkThread(i));// GetLinkThread is a simply class that extends Task<Void> and have call method with getLink() method
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);

        ExecutorService executorService2 = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for(String url : Parser.linkSet){
            executorService2.execute(new GetTextThread(url));// GetTextThread is a simply class that extends Task<Void> and have call method with getText() method
        }
        executorService2.shutdown();
        executorService2.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        Parser.setIsParseEnd(true);//set value when is true program start run javafx window with map

    }
```

It runs ok when I use javaFx and I have a GUI.
When I try run method `parseText();` in my `Parser` class in main it only runs this `executorService2.execute(new GetTextThread(url));` the rest of code doesn't run.

**Java**

In Parser class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        parseText();
    }
```

Why does this happen and how can I run it without a GUI?

Comment: `Task`s try to execute some code on the FX Application Thread (e.g. changes to their `status` property, etc). If the FX toolkit hasn't started, the FX Application Thread won't have started, and so it won't work. (Probably you get an exception which is buried somewhere.) If you want it to be reusable in both UI and non-UI environment, you need to refactor it so the `Task` is only used in the UI environment.

Comment: Also, don't create and shut down executor services on the fly. You may as well just use a thread if you're going to do that. Create one executor service for the duration of the application.

Comment: Depending on the complexity of the code in `GetLinkThread` and in `GetTextThread`, you might as well just run them all in the main thread as parallelization usually makes things more complicated than it is useful.